# Check in view that form have errors?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

(ZF2) Is there a possibility to check in view that the form is displayed for the first time, or "returned" because of errors?

Of course I can in controller base on isValid add additional variable, but I'm curious if there is a ready solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the form has been validated with `$form->hasValidated()` if it hasn't you prob can be pretty sure it's displayed for "the first time".

Additionally you could check if the form contains any error messages `$form->getMessages()`. That way you could tell if it is validated and contains validation errors.